# sharing a git repo and merging it back

Tags: git

So if I have a Git repo on my local machine and I send it to a friend.  He creates a branch (or maybe he doesn't - I don't think it's too important), does some work and sends it back to me.  Now I have two repos: mine, which I have also been working on; and his, with a new branch which he has been working on.

How do I get it all back together!?

Comment: How are you "sending it to a friend"? Git has built-in ways of sharing things, if you're simply copying the repo you're making this harder on yourself than it needs to be.

Comment: What are the built in ways of sharing?

Comment: Look up [`git clone --help`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-clone).

Comment: What if my repo isn't on the web?

Comment: You can use [git bundle](http://progit.org/2010/03/10/bundles.html) to pack up your repo for sneakernet transport

Comment: @Ferguzz Why *wouldn't* it be? If your intent is to share code via distributed version control, there is no good reason not to use the Internet. There are a million free solutions for this. You could also investigate [`git format-patch`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-format-patch) but again, you're making it harder than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you "sending it to a friend"? Git has built-in ways of sharing things, if you're simply copying the repo you're making this harder on yourself than it needs to be.

If you have a second copy of the repo from your friend on your local file system, and you want to merge from it, you can set it as a "remote":

```
$ git remote add other-repo /path/to/other/repo
```

Now you have a remote named `other-repo` pointing at the copy of your repo, and you can fetch the changes your friend made, making your original repo aware of them:

```
$ git fetch other-repo
```

Now that your original repo knows about the branches in `other-repo`, you can merge them in:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge other-repo/master
```

Your master branch will now contain the changes your friend made in `other-repo`'s master branch.